# I think I have a virus

Tags: android-versions

My phone will not download anything from my app store. Everytime I get on my browser I will get a notice that says I have multiple viruses...can I please get help with this issue...and if I have to download an app I can't..

Answer (score -1):

Those things are not viruses rather they are called **Pop-up Ads**. You'll face this pop-ups on almost all the browsers including Chrome, Firefox, Opera etc. These ads always try to install **Malware, Bloatware apps** on your phone when clicked.
***There are two browsers which blocks ads successfully...***
1 - Firefox (with extension AdBlock Plus installed)
2 - UC Mini (with speed-mode enabled)

P.S : Your phone does not have a virus.